# echo $PATH in system() give me a wrong output

Tags: c, linux, shell

This is a piece of code found on Internet

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                     
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    putenv("PATH=/nothinghere");
    //setenv("PATH","/nothinghere");
    system(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

if I do

```
$./a.out "ls"
sh: 1: ls: not found
```

Of course
But what if

```
$./a.out "echo $PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

It print the original `$PATH` !!

If we create a new shell then do the samethings

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    putenv("PATH=/nothinghere");
    //setenv("PATH","/nothinghere");
    system("/bin/sh");
    return 0;
}

$./a.out
$ echo $PATH
/nothinghere
$ ls
/bin/sh: 2: ls: not found
```

Why?
Is it kind of problem about `fork` or the implementation of `echo`?

Comment: Run `set -x` before your command, and it'll show you what it's doing.

Comment: `fprintf(stderr, "argv[1]=%s\n", argv[1]);` would likewise have avoided this confusion.

Comment: I realize that this question is stupid now.....

Comment: @Terrynini We all have to start somewhere :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you're using double quotes, telling your shell to replace `$PATH` with the value of the PATH variable **before it even starts `a.out`**.

The wrong value is thus being inserted not by the shell invoked by `system()`, but by the shell you're interactively typing commands at.

To fix it, change:

```
$ ./a.out "echo $PATH"
```

to:

```
$ ./a.out 'echo $PATH'
```

Comment: Oh... I see, thanks